# How are .exe files managed in windows?

Tags: android, ms-dos

I have a project I am currently working on that involves trying to add MS-DOS functionality to Android 4.1.2 KitKat, also allowing .exe files to be executed. I only have one problem:

I cannot seem to find the process that manages the execution of exe's.

Comment: If you want to add MS-DOS functionality why are you asking about Windows? I am not sure I understand what your trying to achieve.  **You are not going to be able to add the ability for Android to execute Windows executables.**

Comment: QEMU can *emulate* x86 completely in software if I'm not mistaken. If you could port QEMU to Android, you could potentially do this. In fact, I just found this: http://www.bubblews.com/news/444490-run-windows-on-android-with-qemu-ampamp-bochs

Answer (score 1):

In order to get Android to correctly run ms-dos applications in android, you would need a Virtual Machine (So you can run x86 assembler on a pretend PC inside the android VM, and you would need the entire MS-DOS operating system.)

I'd be suprised if there was anything available to do that (it's not impossible), but it would seriously be easier to rewrite any existing Dos Programs for Android as required.

Comment: While its possible to write a virtual machine software that has the capability to run x86 applications on ARM hardware. **The said virtual machine software does not exist.** It does not exist because the hardware itself does not have the capability to emulate x86-64 hardware.  It was only in the last year was 64-bit ARM hardware released, and that hardware, is not running Android